# Rails Trying to access parameters in Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, hash, devise

I've created a User model through Devise gem

My relationships are setup as:

- The User has a many to many relationship with Role
- The User belongs_to (one to many relationship with) Batch
- The User has_one (one to one relationship with) UserProfile

Now everytime a User is created I am calling the method **cup** that creates a UserProfile as well. The problem is that I can't access anything other than devise's own parameters in the Model.

For example I have a drop down to select for Role but i cant access its selected value

My aim is to do something like:

```
  def cup
    if role.title == 'this'
      create_user_profile(:username => 'username01')
    else
      create_user_profile(:username => 'username02')
    end
  end
```

This is what the model looks like:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_and_belongs_to_many :roles
  belongs_to :batch
  has_one :user_profile

  after_create :cup

  def cup
    create_user_profile(:username => 'username')

  end

  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
end
```

My parameters look like this:

> {"utf8"=>"✓", 
>   "authenticity_token"=>"TbsLJxZB2aeDgj8RitTRKURCc3KODCKpv/xphwhAaIw=", 
>   "users"=>{"username"=>"rfdsfew",  "role_id"=>"1",  "batch_id"=>"1"}, 
>   "user"=>{"email"=>"2@223.com",  "password"=>"[FILTERED]", 
>   "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"},  "commit"=>"Sign up"}

I can access the params in **user** hash but not in **users** hash

My guess is that, this is because the users hash is not allowed in devise controller, since I can't access devise's controller I have no idea how to permit the **users** hash.

And I found this on the internet but it didn't work:

```
before_filter :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

protected

def configure_permitted_parameters
  devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) << :username
end
```

Comment: Why do you have a `users` hash *and* a `user` hash?

Comment: because the `user` hash is generated by the devise's own fields and `collection_select` won't let me add its value to the user hash instead i have to use `:users` which generates the `users` hash... for example: `<%= collection_select(:users, :role_id, Role.all, :id, :role)%>`

Comment: params are not accessible in models, even if you pass them as a parameter then it would be consider as bad practice and might also be dangerous.

Answer (score 0):

The main thing is that the extra parameters should be part of `params[:user]`, so change your calls to `collection_select`.

Next you need to make sure that devise allows those extra parameters - that's the purpose of

```
 devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) << :username
```

which you would need to do for each extra parameter. But for array parameters you need to use the longer form:

```
devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) {|u| u.permit(:email, :password, :username, :batch_id, :role_ids => [])}
```

Which brings me to the last change you need: your association with roles is has_and_belongs_to_many: you cannot assign `role_id`, you must assign `role_ids`, which must be an array.

You need to change the name used by the form element to `role_ids` and for rails to parse it as an array you need to add `[]` to the end of it. If you pass `:multiple => true` to the select helpers they should do this for you.

Comment: I keep getting this error `undefined local variable or method `devise_parameter_sanitizer' for #<User:0x007ff0788e3378>`, I've tried everything I could find but nothing fixed it... do you have any idea how to fix it??

Comment: however i did fix the collection_select and the `role_ids` and `batch_id` are now showing under `user` hash instead of `users`

Comment: Sounds like you are calling it in the wrong place - should be in a before filter on your controller

Comment: I changed after_create to `before_create :cup` but I still get the same error

Comment: The devise bits don't belong in your model at all

Comment: But the devise gem itself put those there... where else would they go?

Comment: I was talking about the devise_parameter_sanitizer bits. `devise :database_authenticatable` etc should stay in the model.